# Installed Nhibernate Profiler via nuget but now my project won't run

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-profiler

I have VS 2015 and a web api soultion.

I get this error now

```
Server Error in '/SiteIntegration' Application.

Failed to compile both on .NET 4.5 and on .NET 4.0. 4.5 Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile the following symbols: 'NET40;NET45'
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.0.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.1.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.2.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.3.cs' could not be found
No source files specified

   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String outputFolder, String compilerVersion, Int32 tryCount)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder). 4.0 Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile the following symbols: 'NET40'
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.0.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.1.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.2.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.3.cs' could not be found
No source files specified

   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String outputFolder, String compilerVersion, Int32 tryCount)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder) 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile both on .NET 4.5 and on .NET 4.0. 4.5 Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile the following symbols: 'NET40;NET45'
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.0.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.1.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.2.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.3.cs' could not be found
No source files specified

   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String outputFolder, String compilerVersion, Int32 tryCount)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder). 4.0 Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile the following symbols: 'NET40'
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.0.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.1.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.2.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.3.cs' could not be found
No source files specified

   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String outputFolder, String compilerVersion, Int32 tryCount)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder)

Source Error: 



Line 9:         {
Line 10:            // Initialize the profiler
Line 11:            NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
Line 12:            
Line 13:            // You can also use the profiler in an offline manner.


 Source File:  C:\Users\compName\Source\Repos\Siteintegration\SiteIntegration\App_Start\NHibernateProfilerBootstrapper.cs    Line:  11 

Stack Trace: 



[InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile both on .NET 4.5 and on .NET 4.0. 4.5 Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile the following symbols: 'NET40;NET45'
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.0.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.1.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.2.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.3.cs' could not be found
No source files specified

   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String outputFolder, String compilerVersion, Int32 tryCount)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder). 4.0 Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile the following symbols: 'NET40'
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.0.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.1.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.2.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.3.cs' could not be found
No source files specified

   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String outputFolder, String compilerVersion, Int32 tryCount)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder)]
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder) +859

[InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile both on .NET 4.5 and on .NET 4.0. 4.5 Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile the following symbols: 'NET40;NET45'
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.0.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.1.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.2.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\cq1ln2ls.3.cs' could not be found
No source files specified

   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String outputFolder, String compilerVersion, Int32 tryCount)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder). 4.0 Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile the following symbols: 'NET40'
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.0.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.1.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.2.cs' could not be found
Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\ggvdikxf.3.cs' could not be found
No source files specified

   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileInternally(String fileName, List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String outputFolder, String compilerVersion, Int32 tryCount)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder)
ImageRuntimeVersion: v4.0.30319]
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(List`1 sources, HashSet`1 assemblies, HashSet`1 defineSymbols, String assemblyFileName, String outputFolder) +1189
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.RegisterAppenderUsingNHibernateLogger() +387
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.StartNHibernateProfiling() +170
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize(NHibernateAppenderConfiguration configuration) +172
   SiteIntegration.App_Start.NHibernateProfilerBootstrapper.PreStart() in C:\Users\compName\Source\Repos\Siteintegration\SiteIntegration\App_Start\NHibernateProfilerBootstrapper.cs:11

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +260
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +102
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +434
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +100

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +874
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +169
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +133
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +176
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +120
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +712




Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.81.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NHibernate support people just pointed me in the right direction to fix this.

The problem was that IIS didn't have permissions to access the windows\temp folder.

I went to the IIS AppPool > Advanced Settigns > Identity

And changed it to LocalSystem (since I'm the admin on my PC). That fixed it for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the [latest build](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/Uber-Prof-v3)?

Comment: Having the same problem. I downloaded the latest build but still getting the same error.

Comment: Please contact us at support@hibernatingrhinos.com

Comment: hi I still have this problem with latest, running on local express